# Poco FindMySql.cmake not able to find MySQL source

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I'm working with a bit of a legacy cpp code base. This code base is reliant on Poco, more specifically Poco/MySQL.

When loading Poco via Cmake, it attempts to find the MySQL include and libs. I have the source code of MySQL in a folder nearby, and am attempting to link it in the CMake. While I was able to get the include directory linked correctly, it's still not finding mysqlclient(_r) and I have no idea why. I'm currently attempting in on Mac, but I'd like to make it cross platform as well.

FindMySQL.cmake:

```
find_library(MYSQL_LIB NAMES mysqlclient_r
                 PATHS
                 /usr/lib/mysql
                 /usr/local/lib/mysql
                 /usr/local/mysql/lib
                 /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
                 /opt/mysql/mysql/lib
                 /opt/mysql/mysql/lib/mysql
                 $ENV{MYSQL_DIR}/libmysql_r/.libs
                 $ENV{MYSQL_DIR}/lib
                 $ENV{MYSQL_DIR}/lib/mysql
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../mysql/lib
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../mysql/libmysql)

    message("${MYSQL_LIB}") # MYSQL_LIB-NOTFOUND
```

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server

That's the MySQL source I'm attempting to build.

Comment: Is your MySQL source even built? Does the `mysqlclient_r` library exist one of the folders it is searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long time I found the answer.

Changing it to include_library instead worked fine as it was an include only library.